# Occurrence in two array

Tags: perl

If i have

```
@array1 =(c,a,d,f,t,e,w,e,f,i,s,b,h);
```

and

```
@array2 = (king,blue,beach,sky);
```

how can I check if every word of array2 is valid (is valid when all the letters are in `@array1`, using only once for each letter of `@array1`) ?

Comment: Sorry my english isn't good, but i hope my problem be clear. I solved creating a copy of array1 in a string and deleting elements when I found the occurrence, so if the occurence isnt't found return false. But I'm looking for a more appropriate code.

Comment: It's clear. There was some confusion due to an earlier edit. ysth and I posted a solution. His is better, but I'm leaving mine up for academic purposes.

Comment: Did you intend for there to be duplicates in `@array1`? (`e` and `f` are duplicated.)

Answer (score 2):

This shows the elements of `@array2` that are composed from an arrangement of the letters in `@array1`.

```
my $array1 = join '', sort @array1;

for (@array2) {
   my $pat = join '.*', map quotemeta, sort split //;
   my $re = qr/^.*$pat.*\z/s;
   say if $array1 =~ /$re/;
}
```

---

Tested with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

my @array1 = qw( c a d f t e w e f i s b h );
my @array2 = qw( king blue beach sky );
```

Comment: @ysth's implementation is better.

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1 = qw/c a d f t e w e f i s b h/;
my @array2 = qw/king blue beach sky/;

my $check_word = join '', map "\Q$_\E?", sort @array1;
$check_word = qr/\A(?:$check_word)\z/;

print "checking words with regex: ", $check_word, "\n";

for my $word (@array2) {
    my $dorw = join '', sort split //, $word;
    print "checking $word, transformed to $dorw\n";
    if ( $dorw =~ $check_word ) {
        print "$word is ok\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$word is not ok\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `my ($check_word) = map qr/\A(?:$_)\z/, join '', map "\Q$_\E?", sort @array1;` :o

Answer (score 2):

I'd approach this by using the elements in @array1 to build a regular expression:

```
$regex = '^[' . join('', @array1) . ']+$'
```

will generate this regex from your `@array1`:

```
^[cadftewefisb]+$
```

Then match each element of `@array2` against this regex:

```
for (@array2) {
    print if /$regex/;
}
```

**EDIT**: I wrote this before the question was edited to clarify that each letter in `@array1` may be used only as many times as they appear, i.e. if `t` appears only once in `@array1` then a word in `@array2` may use only one `t`. This answer doesn't satisfy that condition.

Comment: I'm not mistaken, that will print `tweet` if it were added to `@array2`, but it shouldn't. You probably saw the question when it got broken by an edit.

Comment: Hah, indeed, yes, the only-once restriction is new since I saw it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that uses a pair of hashes.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1 = qw(c a d f t e w e f i s b);
my @array2 = qw(cat catt few king blue beach sky);

# Build a hash of unique letters in @array1.
my %letters1 = map {$_ => 1} @array1;

my %letters2;
foreach (@array2) {
    # Build a hash of unique letters of a word in @array2.
    %letters2 = map { $_ => 1 } split //;

    my $status = "OK";

    if (scalar keys %letters2 == length($_)) {
        # No duplicate letters in the word.
        foreach (keys %letters2) {
            $status = "Not OK" if (!exists $letters1{$_});
        }
    } else {
        $status = "Not OK";
    }

    print "$_ => $status\n";
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
cat => OK
catt => Not OK
few => OK
king => Not OK
blue => Not OK
beach => Not OK
sky => Not OK
```